# Is there some web API to query my Stack Overflow profile and score?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, api

On Linux, for [my resume](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/cv-Basile-Starynkevitch.pdf), using LuaLaTex, I would like to automatically update the score I have on SO.

Is there some public API to query the 195K point score and the 0.05% overall I have on June 2020?

It seems that the [type of user objects](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/user-types) is relevant.

Comment: This is the best you can do: `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/841108?order=desc&sort=reputation&site=stackoverflow&filter=!)scTwI3i00OtODDTSG5u`. Total reputation is not available in the API. You could do a SEDE query but that one is hard to automate as it lacks a proper API

Answer (score 5):

That is not available from the API. At best you get your own reputation:

> [`/2.2/users/841108?order=desc&sort=reputation&site=stackoverflow&filter=!LnNkvsiMoAuboSNHiWK3fq`](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/841108?order=desc&sort=reputation&site=stackoverflow&filter=!LnNkvsiMoAuboSNHiWK3fq)

```
{
  "reputation_change_year": 5880,
  "reputation_change_quarter": 3570,
  "reputation_change_month": 1007,
  "reputation_change_week": 29,
  "reputation_change_day": 30,
  "reputation": 195027,
  "user_id": 841108,
  "link": "https://stackoverflow.com/users/841108/basile-starynkevitch",
  "display_name": "Basile Starynkevitch"
}
```

but there is no other endpoint that returns your position in relation to other users.

An alternative is [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1251626?UserId=841108) but that is not easy to automate as SEDE lacks a proper API. You have to script that.

```
;with league as 
(
select rank() over (order by reputation desc) [ranking]
     , id
     , reputation
from users where reputation > 199
)
select ranking
, ranking / convert(decimal,(select count(*) from league )) *100
from league
where id = ##userid?841108:int##
```

This is the result today:

[image: ranking 298 / percentage 0.048187478904117]

SEDE is updated on Sunday.

Comment: If logged in could potentially use https://stackoverflow.com/reputation as well

Comment: @Nick at the end that does show totals for week, month quarter, year but not your position overall. Am I missing something or is that hidden in that stream of data that I didn't notice.

Comment: Sorry, I meant for the reputation total, position would still have to come from SEDE